# Unable to resolve class groovyx.gpars.actor.Actors.actor

Tags: groovy, gpars

I am trying to run the Hello World example from here http://www.gpars.org/webapp/guide/index.html#_download_and_install
But I get the error: Unable to resolve class groovyx.gpars.actor.Actors.actor

I'm using groovy version 2.4.16 and JVM 11.0.3 on linux

This is the code..

```
import static groovyx.gpars.actor.Actors.actor

def decryptor = actor {
    loop {
        react { message ->
            if (message instanceof String) reply message.reverse()
            else stop()
        }
    }
}

def console = actor {
    decryptor.send 'lellarap si yvoorG'
    react {
        println 'Decrypted message: ' + it
        decryptor.send false
    }
}

[decryptor, console]*.join()
```

Comment: Did you forget the `static` in the import line?

Comment: @tim_yates Sadly no.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @tim_yates Done. Added to my question. Thanks

Comment: Works for me out of the box. Any chance that your Groovy installation does not contain gpars?

Comment: @VaclavPech . Can I ask which version of groovy and java? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working I had to do completely remove the old groovy and install the new version with sdkman. Like so..

```
$ apt remove groovy
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
$ sdk install groovy
```

In my case I also needed to add the JAVA_HOME variable.